# Rails - ActiveRecord Reputation System scoped query issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I get the following error  whenever I try to execute `find_with_reputation` or `count_with_reputation` methods.

> ArgumentError: Evaluations of votes must have scope specified

My model is defined as follows:

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_reputation :votes,
            :source => :user,
            :scopes => [:up, :down]
```

The error raises when I try to execute for example:

```
Post.find_with_reputation(:votes, :up)
```

or

```
Post.find_with_reputation(:votes, :up, { order: "likes" } )
```

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Scope-Reputations) isn't very clear on how to get around this error. It only states that the method should be executed as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.find_with_reputation(:reputation_name, :scope, :find_options)
```

On models without scopes ActiveRecord Reputation System works well with methods such as:

```
User.find_with_reputation(:karma, :all)
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It seems that ActiveRecord Reputation System joins the reputation and scope names on the `rs_reputations` table. So, in my case, the reputation names for `:votes` whose scopes could be either `:up` or `:down` are named `:votes_up` and `:votes_down`, respectively.

Therefore, `find_with_reputation` or `count_with_reputation` methods for scoped models need to be built like this:

```
Post.find_with_reputation(:votes_up, :all, { conditions: ["votes_up > ?", 0] })
```

instead of:

```
Post.find_with_reputation(:votes, :up, { conditions: ["votes_up > ?", 0] })
```

Note that you'll need to add the `conditions`option to get the desired results, otherwise it will bring all the records of the model instead of those whose votes are positive, for example.